# please explain jquery autocomplete change event

Tags: combobox, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

In reference to jquery autocomplete combobox, can someone please explain what is the `change` event and when will it be fired ?

From the official doc:

> Triggered when the field is blurred, if the value has changed; ui.item
>   refers to the selected item.

What do they mean by `field is blurred` ?

Comment: `field is blurred` means that it lost focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "blurred" they mean "lost focus" e.g. you click on the field, it gets focus, you then click somewhere else, and the field "blurs".

The [DOM events spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents) says the following (emphasis added):

> The blur event occurs when an element **loses focus** either via the
>   pointing device or by tabbing navigation. This event is valid for the
>   following elements: LABEL, INPUT, SELECT, TEXTAREA, and BUTTON.

The "change" event fires when the field loses focus, if the value of that field has changed:

> The change event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its
>   value has been modified since gaining focus. This event is valid for
>   INPUT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA. element.